# Are we gaining or losing time as our planet revolves around the Sun?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time, time-dilation, estimation

I understand that the Earth (or someone standing on our planet) will undergo time dilation due to a number of reasons compared with someone hovering in interstellar space. I would like to focus on two of those causes. One the time dilation due to the motion around the sun, the other the time dilation caused by the gravitational field of the sun. Now as the Earth orbits the sun it will gain and lose speed relative to the sun which will cause a variation in the amount of time dilation. Likewise as it’s eliptical orbit moves the Earth closer and then further away it will once again cause variation in the amount of time dilation caused by the Sun’s gravity. Now my question is, has anyone been able to calculate the annual amount of both effects on the Earth and if so how much time is ‘lost’ or ‘gained’ once a full orbit of 1 year has been completed? (For the sake of this question I would like to consider these two factors of time dilation in isolation and not others such as the Earth’s spin or the motion of our galaxy)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a fairly routine calculation, e.g. using the open source [Black Hole Perturbation Toolkit](http://bhptoolkit.org/). (Using a nuke to shoot a mosquito here.)

Taking into account the the orbital parameters for the Earth-Sun system, we loose about $0.47$ seconds each orbit due to time dilation, due to the gravitational potential of the Sun and our motion about the Sun.

Not taken into account are any effects due to the galactic potential, proper motion of the Earth-Sun system, and in particular, time dilation due to the Earth sitting in its own gravitational potential. (By comparison, the later contributes about 0.02 seconds per year for somebody sitting at the North pole.)